# @PrimaryKeyColumn annotations must have a type of PARTITIONED for scala Cassandra Spring Data application

Tags: scala, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am working on Cassandra Spring-data module using Scala.  I have created domain model & setup crud repository.

Spring data repository is setup as below:

```
@Repository
trait SampleRepository extends CassandraRepository[Sample, SampleKey]
```

Table domain model is setup as below:

```
@Table
 case class Sample(@PrimaryKey
              sampleKey: SampleKey,
              @Column("surName")
              surName: String)
```

Primary Key is composite key. Id column as Partition key. name column  as Cluster key

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
case class SampleKey(
                  @PrimaryKeyColumn( `type` = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordinal = 0, name = "id")
                  id: Int,
                  @PrimaryKeyColumn( `type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordinal = 1,  name = "name")
                  name: String
                )
```

In scala type is a valid keyword hence used backward quotes.  I am expecting this to work but when I start the application but I get

```
Suppressed: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Composite primary key type [com.barclays.decisionstore.trac.model.SampleKey] has no fields annotated with @PrimaryKeyColumn
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClassEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(PrimaryKeyClassEntityMetadataVerifier.java:91)
    ... 262 common frames omitted
Suppressed: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: At least one of the @PrimaryKeyColumn annotations must have a type of PARTITIONED
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClassEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(PrimaryKeyClassEntityMetadataVerifier.java:98)
    ... 262 common frames omitted
```

This means type parameter to annotation is not recognized by Spring-Data.
The same code with java model classes works without issue.

Would appreciate any pointers or substitute to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually java bean properties not recognized other than annotations.

Scala does not bind instance variables as bean properties by default at `case` classes. For this you need to add `@BeanProperty` annotations to each properties.

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

@PrimaryKeyClass
case class SampleKey(@BeanProperty
                     @PrimaryKeyColumn(`type` = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordinal = 0, name = "id")
                     id: Int,
                     @BeanProperty
                     @PrimaryKeyColumn(`type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordinal = 1, name = "name")
                     name: String)
```

Also if you get an object construction error, add a constructor with default values (this requires to make variables `var`):

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
case class SampleKey(@BeanProperty
                     @PrimaryKeyColumn(`type` = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordinal = 0, name = "id")
                     var id: Int,
                     @BeanProperty
                     @PrimaryKeyColumn(`type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordinal = 1, name = "name")
                     var name: String) {
  def this() = this(0, "")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Actually I wanted to crease simple pojo compatible  with spring-data.  class is much better choice than case class .

Comment: By the way if you need to compare objects, with case classes you get `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` for free (they will be auto generated by scala). with classes you need to implement them by yourself. an annotation looks ugly at first, but in my opinion benefits are much more for data objects.

Answer (score 1):

Its working when used with **class** instated of **case class**.

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
class SimpleKey{

 @PrimaryKeyColumn( `type` = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordinal = 0, name = "id")
 var id: Int =_ 
 @PrimaryKeyColumn( `type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordinal = 1,  name = "name")
 var name: String =_
}
```